# E2E testing with third party services

Tags: testing

I'm actually building an application that relies on multiple third parties (like 10-12) and I'm wondering if I should test my application with its third parties integrations.

I had a discussion with some folks and it seems that the answers vary in a way that I'm not totally sure of what could be better than the other.

My point is that I would stick with the real third parties and test my whole application including their real behaviours because:

- Mocking all of them would be a real pain
- Interactions with the third parties are an inherent part of the system. And if I'm mocking them with some expected behaviour while they are changing the real behaviour, this could drive me in a weird state where my tests are passing but the real app is breaking.

What are your thoughts on including third parties as part of the E2E tests suites instead of mocking them?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between integration and E2E tests is that E2E is trying to run as closely as possible to release configuration. If you were to mock the 3rd parties, or create local testing instances, it would probably not be E2E test.

But at the same time, there should not be many E2E tests. They should be only tip of the testing pyramid. Majority of the behavior should be verified by either fast, isolated unit tests or integration test that runs against local instance of the 3rd party, if possible. E2E tests should only be there as "smoke test" that things are all wired up correctly. They are not for verifying application behavior.